# variable is null although It was set

Tags: java, object, events, null, listener

I build a that contain some objects like that:

```
public class TestThis implements Listener{

    private EventsManager eventsManager;
    private ConfigManager configManager;

    public TestThis() {
        eventsManager = new EventsManager();
        eventsManager.addListener(this);
        configManager = new ConfigManager(this);
    }

    public ConfigManager getConfigManager() {
        return configManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configLoadedSuccessfully(Event event) {
        System.out.println(this.configManager); //OUTPUT NULL
        System.out.println(this.getConfigManager());//OUTPUT NULL
    }
}
```

There is problem with the `configManager` object.
In the construct everything is ok but is `configLoadedSuccessfully` event the `configManager` is null and its null evrywhere.

The Listener Code:

```
public interface Listener{
    public void configLoadedSuccessfully(Event event);
}
```

Comment: Your capitalization is off, not `this.ConfigManager` but rather `this.configManager`. Not sure if this is the problem or not, but I do know that it matters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It was also a problem but it did not solve it.

Comment: Can you show the invocation code and the listener interface?

Comment: @AhmedAgiza I added the code.

Comment: I suspect that `eventsManager.addListener(this);` calls code that ends up invoking `configLoadedSuccessfully` on the parameter (`this` in this case). The null would then be explained because `configManager` is only assigned after this call. So you may need swap the order of the last two statements in the constructor

Comment: @ernest_k But if I do it the event will run before he has a listener.

Comment: @Razdom If that's the problem then you need to redesign your code to eliminate the cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a function that start loading the config and change the order of the var`s create.

```
    public class TestThis implements Listener{

    private EventsManager eventsManager;
    private ConfigManager configManager;

    public TestThis() {
        eventsManager = new EventsManager();
        configManager = new ConfigManager(this);
        eventsManager.addListener(this);
        configManager.load();
    }

    public ConfigManager getConfigManager() {
        return configManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void configLoadedSuccessfully(Event event) {
        System.out.println(this.configManager);
        System.out.println(this.getConfigManager());
    }
}
```